# Showing 3 text character from a 8 character password format

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

***functionality:***

User scan ID with a USB scanner, the ID number(8 characters) is captured and values will be inputted into the `<input type=password>` field. However, instead of showing all 8 bullet point for the ID value captured, only 5 of the characters will be the password type and the remaining 3 will be in text format.

***Issue:***

I have tried searching online but can't seem to find any possible suggestion or solution. I have set my input field type as password, hence at this point all the values in the field is in password type format.

However, what I would like to achieve is that the first 5 characters follow the password type format while the remaining 3 is in text type format.

What I am achieving now:

........

What I hope to achieve:

.....12A

I would like to request for help or to point me in any direction so that I could get this going.

Thanks.

```
<input type="password" id= "NRICCodeField"  style="position:absolute; top:545px; left:690px; height:68px; width:545px; outline: 0; border: 0; font-size:70px; font-color:#765725; font-family:'Gothic'; background: transparent; z-index:100;" autofocus src="lib/image/transparent.png">
```

Comment: You won't be able to use a password field. This will always hide all characters. You'll want to user a `type="text"` I'd imagine and implement the hidding yourself

Comment: Are you open to use JavaScript for it? BTW, you can't achieve it completely with `input type="text"`

Comment: The easiest way I would see this is by having two inputs next to one another, one password and one text, nd jump to the second when the first one has 5 characters. To make it look nice you could make the width of the inputs change in function of how much characters were entered.

Comment: I would agree with Nicovank, you could probably style both fields well enough to make it look like one field. Otherwise as 31piy and Liam said, you could use a text input and javascript to get the functionality you're after.

Comment: @31piy Yes, I could make do with javascript. Certainly, cause if `input type = text`, it will show all the text

Comment: @Luke -- As @nicovank suggested, create two boxes, the left one with `type="password"`, the right one with `type="text"`, then use JavaScript to break the string in (5, 3) characters fragments, and assign to the respective textbox. Also, using CSS to make these two boxes look like one box will do the trick. :)

Comment: @31piy ohh, alright. will give it a try

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way for you, you can review my code in below if it is work for you. You need a proxy hidden field where you should store actual value and text field will be appear for user view only. When form will be submit then you should pick the data from hidden field not text field.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="not-ie" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>41160278</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function applyFormat(self){

    var input = self.value;
    var firstPart = input.substr(0,4);
    var lastPart  = input.substr(5, input.length);

    formname.forShow.value = firstPart.replace(firstPart, '*****') + lastPart;

    formname.forStore.value = input;

}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form action="#" name="formname">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="text" name="forShow" maxlength="8"    onchange="applyFormat(this)" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" name="forStore" value="" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Edit these if you want to switch to another character
  // and/or the number of characters you want to hide
  var unicodeChar = "●", hideNChars = 5;

  // On text input, we turn the hidden characters into their real
  // values, save into data("passcode") and then re-hide the 'n'
  // first characters
  $('#userID').on('input', function(){
    var regex = new RegExp(unicodeChar, "g");
    for (var i = 0, v; match = regex.exec($(this).val()); i++) {
      v = $(this).val();
      $(this).val( v.substr(0, match['index']) + $(this).data("passcode")[i] + v.substr(match['index'] + 1) );
    }
    var value = $(this).val();
    $(this).data("passcode", value).val(Array(value.length <= hideNChars ? value.length + 1 : hideNChars + 1).join(unicodeChar) + value.substr(hideNChars));

    console.log($(this).data("passcode"));
  }).data("passcode", "");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="" id="userID">
```

The value is retrievable in `$('#userID').data('passcode')` but if needed, you can store that data in a hidden input or simply turn the input text clear on form submission.

This code can easily be improved and more sophisticated if needed. (e.g. you might need to know what is the hidden character the user is trying to delete/replace)